# Datapicker binding with angular and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datapicker

I tried to make an datapicker and a time picker for a website, I found the solution on [this site](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I use angular and I don't know how can I do to take the value from the input. I tried with ng-model, but didn't work.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into [Bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It's a collection of Boostrap UI elements, converted into Angular.js directives. You'll find that using Angular.js Directives will have much better data-binding and support and then using the equivalent jQuery/Javascript plugins.

One of the Bootstrap UI components included in the link is the 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker Directive'. To give you an example of what this directive looks like, and what an Angular-friendly datepicker looks like:

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="date" min-date="minDate"></uib-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a directive for DOM manipulation.

```
app.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).datetimepicker();
    }
  }
});
```